# Change text of a TextView using a notification action without opening the app

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have an `Activity` with a `TextView` called `textView`. Within the activity there is a function `void changeText()` which changes the text of `textView`. This function can be called be pressing a `Button` in the activity. Another way to call this function should be using an action of a notification (`NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction`). When the action from the notification is invoked I don't want the activity to show up on the screen. I rather want the activity to invoke `void changeText()` in silence (in the background). When the user enters my app the next time (and it is still alive) he should see the changed text. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want activity show up on screen when clicks on button, you should use PendingIntent.getBroadcast() or PendingIntent.getService()  and save in SharedPreferences as @Ido said

You can create a broadcast receiver in a new file called YourReceiver.java

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //save your value on shared preferences here
        Log.e("test", "receive broadcast");
    }

}
```

And inside AndroidManifest.xml you must declare your receiver

```
<receiver android:name="yourpackage.YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="yourpackage.receiver"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

now you can create the PendingIntent to put on your notification action button

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("yourpackage.receiver")

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
```

I hope this can help you.

More info:

[Tutorial BroadcastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: Thanks. Looks quite promising. Is there a way to make the `BroadcastReceiver` class non-static in order to call a method of my surrounding Activity out of the `onReceive` method?

Comment: to make class non-static you must declare in another file and update android:name receiver from manifest.xml

Comment: I think the problem is still how to call the non-static function of my Activity from the onReceive method. I tried to cast the Activity back from the context given in `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` but it didn't work. Actually, the submitted context is an instance of `android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext` and not of my activity even though I called `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` with first parameter `this`.

Comment: Well, it won't work you need to do a static method on your activity that receives Context, an example if you are saving value on Preferences you just call method that saves it passing Context as a parameter and it should work

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This solution will only work if the application is running in the background, if you want to do it while the application isn't running on the background you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)**

There are few ways to do this, most simply and good one is to simply store a static string inside the activity and when you create/restore to that activity you update the text:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.Override;

public class TextActivity extends Activity
{
    private static String mText;
    public static void setText(String text) { mText = text; }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (mText != null)
            textView.setText(mText);
    }
}
```

Now when you receive the notification you update the text like this:

```
TextActivity.setText("Blah blah");
```

Comment: Can you show me the part how I create the `PendingIntent` for the notification that it doesn't bring my app to the screen? That's my problem. The remaining part works well.

Comment: I didn't quite understood your question, you don't want the app to open with the `PendingIntent` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. The user should be able to invoke that function using the notification without leaving the app which he is using right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). You can save the text you want to display in a key-value pair, then load it and display it in the `TextView` in your `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method.